# How to filter the_content() & include content from template

Tags: plugin-development, filters, the-content

I am trying to filter `the_content()` on single page, but it looks like it is creating an infinite loop. I want to know how to fix this. I want to override `the_content()`.

Is there any other way to override single page content from plugin?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_single_content' );
function change_single_content($content){
    global $post;

    if ( 'my-CPT' == get_post_type() && is_single() ){
        ob_start();
        include my_plugin_theme('single-template.php'); //include single template content
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: What plugin are you referring to?

Comment: Can you please add the code from `my_plugin_theme()` and tell us in an [edit] what `single-template.php` is and where it is from (theme, custom plugin, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that `single-template.php` uses `the_content`. Now think about what happens:

1. Your filter causes `single-template.php` to load
2. `single-template.php` uses `the_content`
3. So `single-template.php` loads again
4. Which uses `the_content`
5. Which loads `single-template.php`
6. Which uses `the_content`
7. ...

I am not entirely sure how to fix that, as your question is light on detail. It is hard to tell what most of the code does or what your ultimate goal is, but it may be as simple as removing the filter conditionally:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_single_content' );
function change_single_content($content){
    global $post;

    if ( 'my-CPT' == get_post_type() && is_single() ){
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'change_single_content' ); // this !!
        ob_start();
        include my_plugin_theme('single-template.php'); //include single template content
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    return $content;
}
```

I am also pretty sure that what you are doing is the wrong way, or at least a less-right way, to do what you are trying to do. I can't prove that, but my spider sense is tingling something awful.

Comment: thanks, but I got which is causing problem. there is a while loop in including file. when I remove while it loads.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_content' );
function filter_content( $content ){
    if ( is_single() ){
        $new_content = str_replace( 'for', 'FOR', $content );
        return $new_content;
    }
    else
    {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Try this. I have tried replacing the_content on single post. It's replacing but not on index page because of `is_single()` condition.

You can tweak it that suits your need.

The problem with you code is that you are accepting `$content` as parameter and returning `ob_get_clean()`. You should return `$content` after tweaking it, in this scenario.

As in the code above, I have accepted `$content`, tweaked it and returned `$new_content`.